# How do I change the hlua::Lua context variable from inside a function?

Tags: rust, hlua

Here's a small example:

```
extern crate hlua;
use hlua::*;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::{Cell, RefCell};

fn main() {
    let lua = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Lua::new()));
    lua.borrow_mut().set("x", 42);
    {
        let lua2 = lua.clone();
        lua.borrow_mut().set("foo", function0(move ||{
            lua2.borrow_mut().set("x", 1); // XXX thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError'
        }));
    }
    let _ = lua.borrow_mut().execute::<()>("foo()");
    println!("{}", lua.borrow_mut().get::<i32, _>("x").unwrap());
}
```

This code panics at runtime at the line marked `XXX`. I get that `lua` is borrowed when I call `foo()`, but I don't see other way to do it. How can I use `lua` from inside an exported function?

Comment: You have provided a good MCVE, but I think it lost some meaning along the way. Your code could boil down to just `lua.execute::<()>("x = 1")`. I'd encourage you to add some prose explaining why you need to call back into the Lua interpreter after just being inside it.